# Advice regarding object oriented design and wrapper methods

Tags: php, oop, factory

I have a State class that includes configuration as well as some state-specific methods. I also have a Factory class that I inhertit my MVC classes from that also has a reference to this State object. This makes sure that all of my MVC objects have specific State-related functionality. For example, my State class includes methods for setting and reading cache or sessions.

My Factory class has a number of methods that are simply wrappers, like this:

```
public function myFunction($data){
    $this->State->myFunction($data);
}
```

The idea is that these methods are defined in Factory, but are actually executed by State object. This allows me to call:
`$this->myFunction();` rather than the longer one that includes State in it, when writing code.

I don't know enough about how PHP works internally, but is this efficient? My thought process has been that since I usually only have one instance of State object, then having method wrappers in my Factory class is better, because otherwise those methods would include a lot of code that is not used most of the time. But I am not sure how PHP works internally.

At times I can have dozen objects that have the parent Factory class and all of them reference the same State object. Is it efficient to have wrapper methods defined in Factory that simply call methods of State, rather than deal with State directly? Or am I just adding additional overhead to the whole system?

My idea was that if Factory is simply a class that is inherited and includes wrappers for a lot of functionality, then I can streamline development more efficiently. Does it save memory if the class that you inherit from has wrappers as opposed to fully defined code in methods?

Comment: I call these methods 'convenience methods', I think if you call them really often, then there's no problem to wrap them. It's one step further to debug, but for me that's not a big problem. At the end it's not much of memory dissipation, because somehow you would need to reference your objects anyway.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm really paranoid about this since the design seems a little dirty in this way, but my Factory class only includes a factory method to dynamically load other objects, send API calls and then bunch of those convenience methods.

Comment: I see a big problem in factories which create objects on a string base; like: `$factory->get('someModel');` *then* it get's dirty because one is not able to do a proper debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, such wrapper has not performance benefit. Actually, what you get this was is an extremely minor loss of performance.

What's more important, this way you are hiding dependencies, which might make it harder to maintain the code.

---

### Few thoughts on your topic

I get the impression, that you are *doing it all wrong <sup>tm</sup>*. Here are the issues, that I have with what you wrote in the question:

- Is the `State` class responsible for configuration *OR* "state specific methods"?

  There is such thing as [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which states, that every class should have a single responsibility. You could also say, that every class should have only one season to change.
- Why do your "MVC classes" inherit from `Factory` class?

  In object oriented code, the keyword `extends` represents an **is-a**  relationship between classes. It's OK to have `class Oak extends Tree`, but when you write `class User extends Table`, it is complete insanity .. and kinda insulting. This is covered by [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (for a simplified  explanation: [look here](http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/liskov_substitution_principle_small.jpg)).
- You have misunderstood the purpose of `Factory` pattern.

  Factory is a creational pattern. This means, that the purpose of factories is to return object instances. Instead of inheriting some methods, which provide access to `State` instance, you should inject it in each of created structure.

  ```
  class Factory
  {
      protected $state = null;

      public function __construct( $state )
      {
          $this->state = $state;
      }

      public function create( $name )
      {
          $instance = new $name( $this->state );
          return $instance;
      }
  }
  ```

  This will have the added benefit that all the structures, which `Factory` instance created, share the same `State` instance.
- Seems like you are trying to have global state thought-out your codebase

  If every in your application need access to instance of `State`, then something is deeply wrong with the whole architecture. You end up with situation where a single object exists in all layers, thus causing a major leak in abstractions. You basically are just hiding a global variable.

Comment: You bring out some really good points here, thanks. I'll respond to each of your points in a separate comment (due to length).

Comment: Yes, my State class has configuration and some methods. I know that I am breaking the single-responsibility rule here, it's a compromise I made, I'll re-evaluate this later on.

Comment: My MVC classes inherit from Factory due to shared functionality. Since all my MVC classes are expected to work the same way - their only difference is their purpose. Basically, when developer writes a model, view or controller, then they can expect the same class functionality to be there (like cache calls). The only reason why there are three, are because of logical standpoint. I technically have one base MVC class, objects of which have different expected roles. My MVC class can be anything, essentially even a separate program that just has access to initialized state and core functionality.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have a global state through-out the codebase, that 'can' be there but is not required. This state can also be replaced at any given time (for testing purposes) and is optional for most of the systems functionality. The idea was to have static-like functionality without having static code (objects can have the same, or different state objects at the same time, though it's rarely more than one). Basically I need the code, that developer writes, to be clean, while at the same time giving them access to the core API on-demand without the core API being static.

Comment: I am accepting this as the correct answer though, since this was the type of feedback I was hoping to get. It made me look at things and the linked article is good.